# Hibernate Annotation for Map with Locale as Key

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I have these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCT (
  ID NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PRODUCT_PK
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
  USING INDEX (
    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX PRODUCT_PK
    ON PRODUCT(ID)
    ...
  )
)
...

CREATE TABLE PRODUCT_LOCALE (
  PRODUCT_ID NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL,
  LOCALE VARCHAR2(12 CHAR) NOT NULL,
  NAME VARCHAR2(160 CHAR),
  CONSTRAINT PRODUCT_LOCALE_PK
  PRIMARY KEY (PRODUCT_ID,LOCALE)
)
...
```

Represented by this class:

```
public class Product extends LocalizedEntity<Product.LocalizedFields> {

  ....

  private Long id;

  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public static class LocalizedFields implements Serializable {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
  }

}
```

And its super class

```
public abstract class LocalizedEntity<T> implements serializable {

  ....

  private Map<Locale, T> localizedFields = new HashMap<Locale, LF>();

  public Map<Locale, T> getLocalizedFields() {
    return localizedFields;
  }

  public void setLocalizedFields(Map<Locale, T> localizedFields) {
    this.localizedFields = localizedFields;
  }
}
```

I was using Hibernate with .hbm.xml files, and this tag was working:

```
.....
<map name="localizedFields" table="product_locale" lazy="false" fetch="select" batch-size="100">
  <cache usage="read-write" />
  <key column="product_id" not-null="true" />
  <map-key type="locale">
    <column name="locale" length="12" not-null="true" />
  </map-key>
  <composite-element class="com.myproject.Product$LocalizedFields">
    <property name="name" type="string">
        <column name="name" length="500" />
    </property>
  </composite-element>
  </map>
.....
```

Now I have to use Annotations, so I've migrated to this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product extends LocalizedEntity<Product.LocalizedFields> {

  ....

  private Long id;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinTable(name = "product_locale", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", nullable = false))
  @MapKeyClass(value = Locale.class)
  @MapKeyColumn(name = "locale", length = 12, nullable = false)
  @BatchSize(size = 100)
  @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
  @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
  @Embedded
  public Map<Locale, LocalizedFields> getLocalizedFields() {
    return super.getLocalizedFields();
  }

  @Embeddable
  public static class LocalizedFields implements Serializable {

    ....

    private String name;

    @Column(name = "name", length = 500, nullable = false)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
  }
}
```

And ...

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class LocalizedEntity<T> implements serializable {

  ....

  private Map<Locale, T> localizedFields = new HashMap<Locale, LF>();

  public Map<Locale, T> getLocalizedFields() {
    return localizedFields;
  }

  public void setLocalizedFields(Map<Locale, T> localizedFields) {
    this.localizedFields = localizedFields;
  }
}
```

And it throws this error:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Map, at table: product, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(localizedFields)]
>       at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:349)
>       at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:322)
>       at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:241)
>       at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:496)
>       at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:270)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1360)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1851)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1930)
>       at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:372)
>       at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:454)
>       at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:439)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
>       ... 103 more

if I replace @MapKeyClass(value = Locale.class) and @MapKeyColumn by @MapKey("locale") throws this error:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Associated class not found: com.myproject.Product$LocalizedFields
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.MapBinder.bindKeyFromAssociationTable(MapBinder.java:133)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.MapBinder.access$000(MapBinder.java:76)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.MapBinder$1.secondPass(MapBinder.java:111)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:70)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1697)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1426)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1846)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1930)
>       at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:372)
>       at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:454)
>       at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:439)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
>       ... 103 more

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the problem is the key "Locale"

According to JPA Documentation (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/index.html?javax/persistence/MapKeyClass.html):

> "Specifies the type of the map key for associations of type
>   java.util.Map. The map key can be a basic type, an embeddable class,
>   or an entity"

Locale isn't a basic type, embeddable or an entity, it's a custom type that Hibernate manages with its internal type "locale" (it's an alias of org.hibernate.type.LocaleType), so JPA has not annotations to manage this.

To resolve it, we must use the annotation @MapKeyType that Hibernate has added to map UserTypes or custom types of Hibernate, instead of annotations of JPA (https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5507).

With these annotations it has to work:

```
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "product_locale", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", nullable = false))
@MapKeyColumn(name = "locale", length = 12, nullable = false)
@MapKeyType(value = @Type(type = "locale"))
@BatchSize(size = 100)
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
```

Answer (score 0):

The annotation **@MappedSuperclass** documentation:

> Designates a class whose mapping information is applied to the
>   entities that inherit from it. A mapped superclass has no separate
>   table defined for it.

When hibernate builds the mapping it creates a **org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass** for each class, and for each property a 'value', there are different types of values depending on annotations (org.hibernate.mapping.ManyToMany, org.hibernate.mapping.OneToMany, org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue, etc). The annotation **@ElementCollection** must be declared as **org.hibernate.mapping.Component** but if you see the stacktrace the error comes from SimpleValue:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Map, at table: product, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(localizedFields)] at **org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue**.getType(SimpleValue.java:349) at ....

Hibernate is ignoring the annotations declared on children, the simple solution is removing the annotation **@MappedSuperclass**.

The other solution would be to tell hibernate from the children that the field has been overwritten, but i've tried with **@AssociationOverride** or **@AttributeOverride** without success.